# Mongoose findOneAndUpdate always creating a new document

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying this :

```
var query= {'boardUrl':data.url,'shapes':data.canvas};
  Shape.findOneAndUpdate(query,query,{upsert:true},function(err,doc){
        if (err){
        console.log(err);
       }

    });
```

What I want is to check if in my Shapes collection there is already a document with with the same boardUrl and update it. If not present, create a new document with the the boardUrl and shapes.

My Shape collection is as follows :

```
var shapeSchema = mongoose.Schema({
boardUrl: String,
shapes: String
});
```

A new document is being created at all times. Could you guys see what's wrong with my query?
Thanks

Comment: You're querying by `boardUrl` **and** `shapes`, but you state, that you only want to check by `boardUrl`.

Comment: oh thanks! If you would put that as an answer, I could choose it as the answer

Comment: Glad it worked, there's already a similar answer, just choose this one ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood, your condition is also including an equality of `'shapes'`, which you don't want. Remove that: your condition should only check `'boardUrl'`

Try:

```
 var condition = {'boardUrl':data.url};
 var doc = {'boardUrl':data.url,'shapes':data.canvas};
 Shape.findOneAndUpdate(condition,doc,{upsert:true},function(err,doc){
    if (err){
    console.log(err);
 }
 });
```

This way, a new document will be inserted when `data.url` is not found. When it's found, `shapes` will be updated to `data.canvas`.

Hopefully this is what you wanted

Answer (score 0):

one method is by validation ,you can user findOrCreate method ,find data if exist update otherwise enter new entry in database

```
Shape.findOrCreate({
 where: shapeCondition
})
.spread(function (Shape, created) {
 if (created == false) {
  (write update query)
  return callback(err);
 } else {

  return callback(null, data);
 }

}).catch(function (err) {
 err.exception = "error message";
 return callback(err);
});
```